# How to insert the value of <option> to the database

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I just want to insert the value or the name of PROVINCE,  CITY and BARANGAY to the database. I'm new in PHP i'm a little confused about this one.

`PHP`

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($link,"mknr2");


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $province = $_POST['province'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $barangay = $_POST['barangay'];




    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(PROVINCE, CITY, BARANGAY) VALUES ('$province','$city','$barangay')";
    if($link->query($sql) === TRUE){
        echo "Sent!";
    }
    else{
        echo "Error:" . $sql . "<br>" . $link->error;
    }


}
?>
```

`HTML`

```
<h2 style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bolder;font-family:arial;margin-left:2%;">Address</h2>
<!--  PROVINCE -->
    <select id="provincedd" name="province" onchange="change_province()" class="province">
        <option>Select</option>
        <?php
            $res=mysqli_query($link,"select * from province");
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
    </select>   
<!--  PROVINCE -->



    <select id="city" name="city" class="city">
            <option>Select</option>     
    </select>

    <select id="barangay" name="barangay" class="barangay">
            <option>Select</option>
    </select>
```

`AJAX.php`

```
<?php
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($link,"mknr2");

if(isset($_GET["province"]))
{
$province=$_GET["province"];

        $res=mysqli_query($link,"select * from city where province_id=$province");
        echo "<select id='citydd' onchange='change_city()'>";
        echo "<option>"; echo "Select"; echo "</option>";
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
        {
        echo "<option value='$row[id]' selected >"; echo $row["name"]; echo "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
}


if(isset($_GET["city"]))
{
    $city=$_GET["city"];

        $res=mysqli_query($link,"select * from barangay where city_id=$city");
        echo "<select>";
        echo "<option>"; echo "Select"; echo "</option>";

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
        {
        echo "<option value='$row[id]' selected>"; echo $row["name"]; echo "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
}



?>
```

`JAVASCRIPT`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function change_province()
{
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php?province="+document.getElementById("provincedd").value,false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
city.style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("city").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

 if(document.getElementById("provincedd").value=="Select")
 {
 document.getElementById("barangay").innerHTML="<select><option>Select</option></select>";
 }


}

function change_city()
{
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php?city="+document.getElementById("citydd").value,false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
document.getElementById("barangay").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

}
</script>
```

Comment: what issue you are facing?

Comment: only the id in the  database is inserting to my table.. i want to  insert the name of the province,  city and barangay itself.

Comment: I got your point, you want to insert id with name, for that you need to write a select query with where condition after receiving posted value. for example :

$city_id = $_POST["city"];
$query = "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE id = $city_id";
$data = mysqli_query($link,$query);
$city_name = $data->fetch_object()->city_name

Now city name you have in variable so use that variable in insert query
..... like this you need to write

Comment: That code is for callback 'option' in you form, you need just add new page to form and update/insert with a simple query..

Comment: are you getting values by using $_POST?

Comment: @Manikanta - i want to insert the name of the province, city and barangay. not the id because my ID column is incremented in the database.

Comment: @UmarAbdullah - Yes, but the only the id is posting in the database, not the name of the province itself.

Comment: check the code there is no value provided for city selectbox

Comment: @JatinParmar the value is in the ajax.php

Comment: @AlbertCervantes 1. you dont include db connection into codes. `$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");` this is an empty connection see this for right db connection : https://tryphp.w3schools.com/showphpfile.php?filename=demo_db_select_proc I recommend you to spend some time on that side

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement)

Comment: @AlbertCervantes please check my answer,hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

you have set Inside  set value to option value and insert this option value in database .

```
<select name="id" required="" onchange="change_province()" class="province">
        <option value="">SELECT CITY</option>
        <?php
            $res=mysqli_query($link,"select * from province");
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
            ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></option>

            <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

**data insert**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($link,"mknr2");


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $province = $_POST['province'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $id= $_POST['id'];




    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(PROVINCE, CITY, BARANGAY) VALUES ('$province','$city','$id')";
    if($link->query($sql) === TRUE){
        echo "Sent!";
    }
    else{
        echo "Error:" . $sql . "<br>" . $link->error;
    }


}
?>
```

Comment: ID should be auto increment. your answer wont work.

Comment: yea its not working... @Dilek if i set it to Auto increment, did it work?

Comment: @AlbertCervantes this is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59782595/12232340 dont forget to upvote :)

Comment: Thanks, but i dont even get it..  i want the actual answer for my question huhu.

Comment: How can I do it in PHP? I mean what is the code or statement to use so that the php will insert the name of the province into the users table.

Comment: i have try it my codeigniter eCommerce project it still working

Comment: yes, but i have a value id on my option, that's why its getting the id of the table... i can't change that option value because its function is to get the data inside the database thru ajax

Answer (score 0):

**Whats wrong with your code?**

your select box will not have any option to select
as i can see in code

(a)you have not assigned any values to it.

```
 <select id="city" name="city" class="city">
        <option>Select</option>     
 </select>

<select id="barangay" name="barangay" class="barangay">
        <option>Select</option>
</select>
```

(b)your javascript to call ajax.php which render select box with options will never executed as change_province,change_city functions will not be executed on any event
in this case if your form will be submitted without selecting province,on server side your post array will be like following

```
["submit"=>"value of submit","province"=>"","city"=>"","barangay"=>""]
```

now if you take look on your code to insert value your query for inserting data will be  like this

```
INSERT INTO users(PROVINCE, CITY, BARANGAY) VALUES '','','')
```

causing to insert new record with id(in case id is auto-increment and these values are nullable)

**What should you do?**

(a)instead of making ajax call to fill select box you should render them at once inside form view

formview.php

```
      <h2 style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bolder;font-family:arial;margin-left:2%;">Address</h2>
      <!--  PROVINCE -->
      <select id="provincedd" name="province" onchange="change_province()" class="province">
          <option>Select</option>
           <?php
              $res=mysqli_query($link,"select * from province");
              while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
           ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["name"];?></option>
          <?php } ?>
       </select>   
      <!--  PROVINCE -->
      <?php
          $res=mysqli_query($link,"select * from city");
            echo "<select id='citydd' onchange='change_city()'>";
            echo "<option>"; echo "Select"; echo "</option>";
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
              {
               echo "<option value='$row[id]' selected >"; echo $row["name"]; echo "</option>";
              }
              echo "</select>";

          $res=mysqli_query($link,"select * from barangay");
          echo "<select>";
          echo "<option>"; echo "Select"; echo "</option>";
          while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
               {
                echo "<option value='$row[id]' selected>"; echo $row["name"]; echo "</option>";
               }
          echo "</select>";
     ?>
```

(b)inside your code to insert data ,you should put some server side(also front-end) validation before making insert to data table(you can search google for it),this will prevent any empty entry to be inserted.
hope this will help you.

Comment: It worked! but all the data in city is displaying on dropdown... All I want  is to display the city/cities depends on the province that you have clicked.

Comment: @AlbertCervantes in that case you should update city selectbox by calling change_city function on call change of province selectbox